# Error during setup LinkedIn SDK in Android Studio

Tags: android, sdk, linkedin-api

I am trying to set up LinkedIn sdk in Android Studio, but in build.gradle file I am getting following :

```
Error:(18, 0) 'com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin' does not implement the Plugin interface.
```

at following line :

```
subprojects { subproj ->
    subproj.plugins.withType(com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.class) {
        subproj.android {
            compileSdkVersion _compileSdkVersion
            buildToolsVersion _buildToolsVersion
        }
    }
}
```

Please guide me how I can solve this issue so that I can move further.

Comment: try adding this line in gradle `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Comment: @Bhargav still getting same issue, also not getting any help regarding this on google.

Comment: I fixed it by creating new project and importing linkedIn-sdk library into my project and added sample project classes to my project

Answer (score 1):

add followed code to your head of build.gradle, 
replace `2.0.0-beta5` to the newest version

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta5'
}
```